# How does the F-35 hover?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, vtol, thrust-vectoring, f-35

[image: Lockheed Martin F-35 hovering]

The picture shows the aircraft hovering; how does it do that?

Comment: Because it's got one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_LiftSystem) ?

Comment: @AakashM doesn't it also have thrust vectoring at the rear?

Comment: @Notts90 that's one of the parts of the LiftSystem

Comment: What prevented you from looking up F-35 on Wikipedia? (Or some other source on the internet). Here's a link to section of the B-(STOVL-)variant:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Martin_F-35_Lightning_II#F-35B . Or what is your specific question not answered in this section?

Comment: @Scrontch A group of people with common interest, passions, knowledge and experience got together and created an online forum where other people could come and ask questions. Now imagine we are all gathered in a bar and invited people to come along.  You've just done the equivalent of then telling them to go away because they can find the answer somewhere else. This is not a close reason, nor is it a reason to reject a question.  If it where, half the questions and answers on here would not exist.

Comment: Similar to this [question](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31925/how-does-the-f-35s-roll-posts-work-and-how-does-its-engine-turn-down-90-degree/31928?s=9|0.7412#31928)

Comment: @Simon: Fair point. That being said, i think it's also considered good netiquette in any internet community when the asker somehow proves to show that he's invested say 5 mins on researching the topic himself before asking. I failed to see that being the case here.

Answer (score 11):

The F-35 has what is called the [Rolls-Royce LiftSystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_LiftSystem). This Contains one lift fan in the middle of the aircraft, and a rotating jet exhaust to provide vertical thrust, and two rotating nozzles to provide stability. The pilot pushes a button, and doors on the aircraft open for the lift fan, while the exhaust nozzle rotates downward.
The pilot controls the thrust and pitch/roll, while a computer double checks what he does to maintain stability.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW28Mb1YvwY) is a good video of it in action and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZD-J1KksHUQ) is a video that has a nice animation of it working.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the picture above is USMC (US Marine Corps),s F-35B, which he have a STOVL (Short Take-Off and Vertical Landing) capability. That aircraft hovers using a Rolls-Royce Allison fan to lift itself. The Rolls-Royce Lift System works like this image:[image] The lifting system itself moved by the F-35's engine. The pilot works at the pitch of the fan, meanwhile computer countermeasures how to maintain stability. The pilot itself could push a button or use voice-activating system to open the lift-fan's door.

Comment: Hi.  Please edit your answer to include the attribution for the image.